# How to get the value using getElementsByTagName

Tags: java, xml, w3c

How to get the value of the tag name using getElementsByTagName. My Xml file is

```
<parent>
<method>name</method>
....
....
</parent>
```

Here i want to take the value of method alone.
i used the following piece of code, but i am getting as object

```
File fXmlFile = new File(FILE_XML);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getElementsByTagName("method").toString();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`doc.getElementsByTagName("method")` returns a [`NodeList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html).

You want the first one of these, so you should use `doc.getElementsByTagName("method").item(0)` - which returns a [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

From this, you probably want the value; `doc.getElementsByTagName("method").item(0).getTextContent()` should get you that.

Comment: Be aware that the search is recursive. Child elements will also appear in the NodeList. E.g. if you want to make sure that your "<parent>" is really the parent, you should add extra checks.