# get child nodes from parent (xml, java)

Tags: java, xml

**UPDATE**
i was specifically targeting staff under some root node, not all "staff" elements in the whole document. i forgot to mention this important detail in the question. sorry guys.

i found this answer to my question:
[getElementsByTagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947248/getelementsbytagname)

But with this data:

```
<one>
<two>
    <three>
        <company>

            <staff id="1001">
                <firstname>Golf</firstname>
                <lastname>4</lastname>
                <nickname>Schnecke</nickname>
                <salary>1</salary>
            </staff>
            <staff id="2001">
                <firstname>Audi</firstname>
                <lastname>R8</lastname>
                <nickname>Rennaudi</nickname>
                <salary>1111111</salary>
            </staff>
            <staff id="2002">
                <firstname>Skoda</firstname>
                <lastname>xyz</lastname>
                <nickname>xyz</nickname>
                <salary>0.1</salary>
            </staff>

        </company>
    </three>
</two>
</one>
```

and this code:

```
public static void parseXML2() {
    File fXmlFile = new File("src\\main\\java\\staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("test");
       System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0).getTextContent());

}
```

i dont get just one staff element, but all of them. how come?
i was expecting to get:

```
                Golf
                4
                Schnecke
                1
```

but instead i get this:

```
                Golf
                4
                Schnecke
                1


                Audi
                R8
                Rennaudi
                1111111


                Skoda
                xyz
                xyz
                0.1
```

looks like your post is mostly code, please add more details...yes the details are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. If you want to get the text contents of the first `staff` node, then get the elements by **that** tag name:

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("staff").item(0).getTextContent());
                                         // ^^^^^^
```

#### Update

In case you want to get the first `staff` node under `company`, then you can find them with node type and node name checks. Here is a rudimentary loop to do this:

```
    Node companyNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0);
    NodeList companyChildNodes = companyNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < companyChildNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = companyChildNodes.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && Objects.equals("staff", node.getNodeName())) {
            System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
            break;
        }
    }
```

You might want to refactor the `for` loop into a separate method.

You can use XPATH too. I think it's more concise:

```
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//company/staff[1]");
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println(nl.item(0).getTextContent());
```

Explanation:

- `//company` selects all the company tags, regardless where they are in the xml. It's the `//` that ignores the rest of the xml structure.
- `//company/staff` selects all the `staff` tags that are under `company` tag.
- `[0]` selects the first such item.

Comment: this would get all "staff" items in the whole document is suspect? this is precisely what i do not want. also i could have clarified that in my question. i need all "staff" under a specific root node

Comment: Updated the post with two alternative solutions which do exactly what you need.

Comment: in your first example i changed this line: if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.getNodeName().equals("staff")) {

not really sure where the "Objects" comes from

Comment: `java.util.Objects` was introduced in java 7. It provides convenience methods. E.g. `Objects.equals()` is a null-safe wrapper around the `equals` method. It's unnecessary here. However, generally I prefer to use `Objects.equals()` so my code will be safe no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line of code which gets the text content from the first company.

```
 System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0).getTextContent());
```

This gets all the text content in the first company node which in this case is the data inside 3 staff elements. If you want to select the first staff element, you can either select it by name or by getting the first child of the company.

Comment: your answer was of course right, but my question was not really formulated that good and i can only give one green arrow. sorry.

Comment: @J. Doe your first comment says I am wrong, then your next comment says I am right, please can you remove the first comment to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml has a format like you mentioned, and with this line of code,

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0).getTextContent();
```

you are printing ALL contents under the COMPANY tag name, thus its gonna print   **EVERYTHING** in company, if you want to select to print only 1st staff, change tagname in the sysout to "staff" and item variable to (0,1,2,3 -> index of wanted staff)

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("staff").item(0).getTextContent();
```

i havent tried this out, but i think its gonna work