# How to select element in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

New to JavaScript. I'm trying to get a header element that disappears when scolling down, and appears when scrolling up.

Why isn't this selecting the `<header>` element?

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("header").style.top = "-72px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
} 


header {
    height: 72px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

But if I add an ID to the `<header>` I can select it using the following

document.getElementById("navbar")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value using getElementsByTagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947248/how-to-get-the-value-using-getelementsbytagname)

Comment: Sorry don't understand that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Sorry don't understand a word of it. The answer below answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an HTMLCollection which is like an array. You need to do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.top = "0";
```

or use [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which accepts CSS selectors and returns the first element matched:

```
document.querySelector("header").style.top = "0";
```